# Instance member cannot be used on type Class?

Tags: swift, init

I'm trying to access the `name` variable from Indicator class, which inherits from Person. However, I believe I'm not doing my initialization right.

I get the following: 'error: instance member 'name' cannot be used on type 'Indicator'`.

```
class Person {
    var name: String

    init(myName: String){
        self.name = myName
    }

    deinit {
        Indicator.letKnowPersonDeinitialized()
    }
}


class Indicator: Person {
    convenience init() {
        self.init()
    }

    static func letKnowPersonDeinitialized() {
        print("\(name)")
    }
}
```

Comment: You declared `letKnowPersonDeinitialized` as a static function. You can't access instance variables from a static function, exactly as the error message says, because a static function isn't related to an instance.

Comment: Incidentally, calling a method of a subclass from a superclass, particularly a static method of a subclass from a superclass deinitializer, is horrifying on numerous levels. It's not clear what you are trying to accomplish, but this design is definitely the wrong way to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot access non-static stuff directly in a static method.

The method `letKnowPersonDeinitialized` is static because it is modified with the `static` modifier:

```
static func letKnowPersonDeinitialized() {
  ^
  |
here!
}
```

The `name` property of `Person` is not static because it is not modified by `static`.

Since non-static members belong to each individual instance of that class and static members belong to the class itself, static members have no direct access to non-static members. They can only access non-static members when an instance is present.

To solve your problem, add a parameter to the `letKnowPersonDeinitialized` method:

```
static func letKnowPersonDeinitialized(person: Person) {
    print(person.name)
}
```

And in the deinitializer:

```
deinit {
    Indicator.letKnowPersonDeinitialized(self)
}
```

---

#### VERY IMPORTANT STUFF:

I don't think your code is designed well. This is not how you use inheritance.

Inheritance means "is a kind of". So if `Indicator` inherits from `Person`, it means that an indicator is a kind of person.

According to common sense, an indicator is not a person. Therefore, it is not suitable to use inheritance here. It makes little sense.