# having difficulties calling functions in a different view controller

Tags: swift

I'm having some difficulties calling a function in a view controller that is different than the one it was declared in. I've tried some methods from different posts on the site, but none of them are working for me.

```
class Housekeeping: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

var balance = 387563 //remove later, arbitrary value for testing
var username = "kaplan"
@objc func addTop() {
    let balanceLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 30))
    balanceLabel.text = "\(balance)"
    balanceLabel.textAlignment = .center
    balanceLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
    balanceLabel.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.center.x*2-95, y: 50)
    balanceLabel.textColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 160/255, green: 160/255, blue: 160/255, alpha: 1.0)
    view.addSubview(balanceLabel)

    let genechipImg = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "genechip"))
    genechipImg.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
    genechipImg.center = CGPoint(x: balanceLabel.center.x + 60, y: balanceLabel.center.y)
    view.addSubview(genechipImg)

    let usernameLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 130, height: 30))
    usernameLabel.text = "Dr. \(username)"
    usernameLabel.textAlignment = .center
    usernameLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
    usernameLabel.center = CGPoint(x: 80, y: 50)
    usernameLabel.textColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 160/255, green: 160/255, blue: 160/255, alpha: 1.0)
    view.addSubview(usernameLabel)
}
```

}

This addTop function was declared in a view controller named `Housekeeping` and I'm trying to call it on a second view controller named `GeneLibrary` but I can't figure out how. As you can see, the function doesn't do much just adds two labels at the top, which I'm trying to add on a subsequent view controller. Here's the second view controller I'm trying to pass it to:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("gene library scene running")
    }
}
```

If anybody could please provide some insight I'd really appreciate it. Stay safe everybody, thanks!

Comment: Try `Delegates'  [https://medium.com/better-programming/3-methods-for-communicating-between-classes-in-swift-4-using-the-model-view-controller-3673f14c70b2]

Comment: @DilanAnuruddha that page doesn't exist

Comment: https://medium.com/better-programming/3-methods-for-communicating-between-classes-in-swift-4-using-the-model-view-controller-3673f14c70b2

Answer (score 0):

Without a context of your app, The solution is:

```
GeneLibrary().addTop()
```

This will get to the function and print `hello`, but I believe this is not your intention, as `GeneLibrary()` creates a new instance from `GeneLibrary` view controller, while there might already be another instance that you want to call in order to do what you want.

if you can provide more details I'll be glad to help.

## UPDATE

as the second view controller is being presented:

```swift
let housekeepingVC = presentingViewController as? Housekeeping
housekeepingVC.addTop()
```

this will do the job

Comment: Yeah, absolutely. Sorry for being a little ambiguous. I edited it into the main post.

Comment: @MatthewKaplan let me assume, let's say you have a view controller of type `Housekeeping` that is presented and then another view controller is being presented or pushed on top of it? or are those two view controllers in a `TabBarController`? this matters so that I guide you to get to what you want exactly

Comment: The second view controller is being presented modally.

Comment: @MatthewKaplan updated, and consider delegation as it is better way of handling this kind of communications

Answer (score 0):

Declare your function as `static`:

```
static func addTop() { print("hello") }
```

Then call it like so:

```
Housekeeping.addTop()
```

Comment: That just creates more errors, like: `Instance member "balance" cannot be used on type "Housekeeping"` I edited in the whole code, if that makes any difference. Thanks!

Comment: The code in your question has changed after my answer. Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37201612/3780985) answer to understand & fix that error.

Comment: I can make the variables static but how do I make the viewcontroller static?

Comment: No, do not make your View Controller static for this purpose. This does not seem the right approach anymore with your new code. It seems better to use a delegate and protocol for your purpose. By using a delegate and a protocol, you can properly call a function in another View Controller. Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60844319/3780985) answer if you would like to get more info about that topic.